# Laravel Query Scope with Pivot

Tags: laravel

I have a query scope that works right now retrieving the right entry I want but I need to get the pivot info as well. For instance:

My Query Is:

```
public function scopeProgramDate($query, $program, $date)
{
     return $query->whereHas('weeks', function ($q) use( $program, $date ){ 
                $q->where('date', $date); 
                $q->where('program', $program); 
      }); 
}
```

So I can call it like `Workout::programdate( 'skunks', Carbon::today() )->first();` and it will return the correct `workout`. But I would like it to include the pivot information for the entry on the pivot table (`date, program, warmup`);

If I call it this way `Workout::programdate( 'skunks', Carbon::today() )->with('weeks')->first();` it will give me the all the weeks associated with the workout which I can't use since a workout can be in the same day with a different `warmpup` and `program`

is there a way to do like:

```
public function scopeProgramDate($query, $program, $date)
 {
     return $query->whereHas('weeks', function ($q) use( $program, $date ){ 
            $q->where('date', $date); 
            $q->where('program', $program); 

     })->withPivot( ['program', 'warmup', 'date'] ); 
  }
```

so I can find a `workout` within `week_workout` where the `date` and `program` matches. Then return the `workout`, `workout.pivot.date`, `workout.pivot.program`, `workout.pivot.warmup` for that entry?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a new function that works but I dont think would be the correct way:

```
public static function workoutWeek( $date, $program){

            $array = array();

            $skill = DB::table('week_workout')
                        ->where('date', $date )
                        ->where('program', $program )
                        ->first();



            $workout   = Workout::find( $skill->workout_id );

            $array['skill']     =  $skill;
            $array['workout']   =  $workout;

            return $array;
        }
```

then call it like

```
$training  = Workout::workoutWeek( Carbon::today(), 'training' );
```